# Python cgi weird behaviour

Tags: python, cgi

I have a simple CGI python script with an html output:

```
print "Content-Type: text/html"
print
print hours,minutes,seconds,","
```

When I run it from my linux shell, it runs fine but when called from the browser, all I get is a blank page. I used to have this problem before when I used CRLF EOF instead of LF but I changed that and it worked fine until some recent modification.

I don't know what to do when the script runs fine from shell but not when called from a browser.

Comment: Hard to tell just from the pasted code. Please paste the values of `hours`, `minutes`, and `seconds`, and try substituting a constant string for that print (i.e. `print "hello world"` instead of `print hours,minutes,seconds,","`).

Comment: It doesn't matter. Even if I do print "hello" I still get a blank page. The source of the blank page is:

Comment: <!-- SHTML Wrapper - 500 Server Error -->

Comment: Are you sure the server is using Python 2? If it's using Python 3, this code will raise an exception. That might account for the error. Check your permissions, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<!-- SHTML Wrapper - 500 Server Error -->` means that something is going wrong on the server. The most common cause in CGI scripts for this error is that there is an uncaught error in the CGI script itself, causing it to prematurely terminate. Your best bet is to check your Apache error logs. These will normally be in `/var/log/<name of Apache install>/error.log` (This could be /var/log/apache2/error.log or /var/log/httpd/error.log, etc.)

Since you've said that this works well in the shell, my guess is that this is an issue with `sys.path` (remember, Apache is a different user, it will have different settings), but I would need to see more to be certain.

Other issues could be:

- Different Python version (3 vs. 2)
- File has the wrong permissions (755 is the standard, I believe)
- Syntax error somewhere in Python which is environmentally dependant

Comment: Also -- use the cgitb module for useful tracebacks if the error is in your code and isn't a server problem http://docs.python.org/library/cgitb.html

Comment: I figured it out. But I don't understand why... I was sacing the file in Notepad++ using UTF8 encoding. After changing to ANSI, it all worked.